# Solution file is not visible once I create a website or project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005

I have installed VS 2005 newly.I tried to create a new three tier application.

```
1) First I added a new blank solution
2) Then I right clicked on the solution and added a new web site
3) once the new web site is created the solution file is not visible
```

because of this reason I am not able to add the new project to the same solution.

What would be the reason for this?

Please help...

Thanks,
Jebli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions, check "Always show solution".

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, there is no solution file for a website. In case you need to have one, you can convert your project to a web application instead.

Comment: my issue is i could not view the solution file. both for project and web site that is creates.I cannot create more than one layer.Dont know what is the issue